# OnActionExecutionAsync Calling himself after Throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core

in my scenario I'm needed to stop the application when throwing that exception.

```
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        int approvalId = 0;
        switch (this.parameterLocation)
        {
            case ParameterLocation.Url:
                approvalId = Convert.ToInt32(context.ActionArguments["id"]);
                break;

            case ParameterLocation.Body:
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown parameter location");
        }         
        var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IValidatorService>();
        var badge = ChecksumUtils.GetBadgeFromToken(context.HttpContext);
        var valid = await service.ValidateApprovalRequest(approvalId, badge);

        if (!valid)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(ResponseMessages.UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS_CONTROLLER);
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }    
    }
```

And I have in my startup.cs inside Configure:

```
   app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {

            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                var exception = errorFeature.Error;
                var responseDetails = new BaseResponse<Object>();

                switch (exception)
                {                    
                    case UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedAccessException:
                        responseDetails.CreateResponse(exception, Models.Enums.InternalCode.Unauthorized);
                        responseDetails.httpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        break;                            
                    default:
                        if (exception is Exception)
                        {
                            responseDetails.CreateResponse(exception, Models.Enums.InternalCode.GenericError);
                            responseDetails.httpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        }
                        break;

                }

                string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseDetails, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });

                context.Response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(responseDetails.httpStatusCode);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
            });

        });
```

My problem is the application is calling these two methods twice, first call OnActionExecutionAsync and do all the validations, if throw new UnauthorizedAccessException calls the method on startup.cs, in this method instead the application return with error to the user, calls OnActionExecutionAsync again and OnActionExecutionAsync call startup.cs one more time, in this second time return with an error.
Any advice?

Comment: I tried with OnActionExecuting either, and have the same result...

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation from Swagger with 401 HTTP status code specifically when calling the same request with postman or frontend app, it's run all normally.